# Парсинг сайта в java

Tags: java, html, json, парсер

Всем привет. Необходимо получать главный текст по ссылке. В этом проблем особо нет, благо json все ещё работает, но проблема в том, что надо получать текст с любого сайта(если текст там есть) и при этом, не нужно получать хлам(комменты, разделы меню, и т.д ) есть ли какое то решение?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно распарсить html, то Jsoup для этой цели подойдет. Там можно задать, какие именно элементы вам нужны.

Comment: Это я в курсе. Вопрос не в том чтобы распарить 1 сайт, а в том чтобы из всех сайтов(или из большинства) получать инфу. Инфа это текст. И вот тут проблемы, т.к. сайты пишут разные люди, и кто то пишет норм, кто то не норм. Кто то посещает инфу в тэг с атрибутом контент, кто то туда и переходы на другие страницы кладет, а у кого то и нет вовсе такого тэга. Как быть во всех этих случаях?

Comment: Такой универсальный парсер вряд ли удастся сделать. Но можно вручную делать парсер для каждого сайта. Здесь тебе поможет паттерн "Стратегия"

Answer (score 0):

В общем резюмируя: супер решения для своей проблемы я не нашел, но методом проб и ошибок вывел такой вид селектора для Jsoup

```
document.select("div[class*='content'] p").text();
```

Это не поможет получить вам главный текст со всех сайтов в мире, но русскоязычные сайты оно парсит ~ процентов на 70. Может кому будет полезно.